# How to split an app's data per domain instead of per app instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku

Let's say you build a simple blog system.

Instead of having to publish this blog system across 3 different Heroku dynos which would be expensive for something so simple (requiring at least 2 dynos each so it wouldn't idle)... there's the option of possibly splitting the logic of 3 different domains on one app.

How would you take the logic and data currently in place for one instance of the app, and then split it up so 3 different domains can use the data scoped to that domain? This is taking existing data to form this system.

Sorry if this wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point all three domains at the same app.

You will need to create a domain model to handle this.

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs
  belongs_to :admin
  validates_uniqueness_of :domain_string
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   before_filter :get_domain


   def get_domain
      @domain = Domain.find_by_domain_string(request.host)
   end

end

class BlogController < ApplicationController

   def index
      @blogs = @domain.blogs.whatever_additional_logic_you_need
   end

end
```

Everything else would follow about the same pattern.